# powershell script does not run on all pcs in domain via GPO

Tags: active-directory, powershell, group-policy

I have a simple Powershell script in domain group policy that writes Username and PCName to network share into  text file.
Unfortunatelly not all PCs write info to files on network share. Some of them have the same build number Windows 10. I see GPO applied to PC, but no file on network share for this PC...
Thank you.

Comment: This would be expected as workstations are configured by default to not wait on the network connection.

Comment: Can you clarify how the script is executed? GPO Computer startup script? Scheduled task? Also check the applied PowerShell execution policy.